# Lista Com Array Gigantesco

Tags: python, array, lista

O software da como output uma lista com apenas um array gigante:

```
[array([0.000000e+00, 1.687500e-01, 5.062500e-01, ..., 3.616745e+03,
   3.617745e+03, 3.618245e+03])]
```

Meu objetivo era obter uma lista, com cada item desse array, separadamente. Para isso, eu tentei fazendo com o seguinte código:

```
lst = [item.tolist() for item in lst]
```

No entanto, meu resultado apenas tira o "array", pois a lista continua com apenas um item.

```
list = [[0, 0.16, 0.501...]]
```

meu objetivo era que list fosse:

```
list = [0, 0.16, 0.501...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se há apenas uma lista dentro de outra e você quer pegar a lista de dentro, você pode usar:

```
list = lst[0]
```